# Modifier Panel not showing in graph editor sidebar

Tags: animation, interface, edit-mode, fcurves, curve-modifier

[image]

I'm trying to add a noise modifier to my camera rotation but it doesn't seem to affect the values. The only thing I also see in the sidebar on graph editor is the "Show Cursor" panel. I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: select only one of your tracks?

Answer (score 1):

it happened because you selected the wrong thing

let me explain 
there are some objects in the blender that won't show the modifier panel.

like:

- Camera
- Light
- Empty object
- Bone

because there is nothing to change with the modifier on that object.

you can select one of your mesh objects (like your motorcycle model) and the modifier panel will show.